# In Fisher’s discriminant for multiple classes, How do you manage when $(Sw)$ is singular matrix (so you cant get $(Sw)^{-1}$)?

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, pattern-recognition, discriminant

I am trying to use Fisher’s discriminant for multiple classes to reduce the Dimension of the MNIST data set, similar to this post: https://towardsdatascience.com/an-illustrative-introduction-to-fishers-linear-discriminant-9484efee15ac

But in my Implementation in Python, when I compute $Sw$ it is a singular matrix so I can not get  $(Sw)^{-1}$ to obtain the eigenvectors from  $(Sw)^{-1}Sb$. Am I doing something wrong or what can I do to solve this problem?

I am following the steps given in Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning By Bishop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it could be singular. This is known as the small sample size (SSS) problem.

A very typical way is to use the pseudoinverse to estimate the required directions.

There have been extensive research to this problem. [Here](http://repository.usp.ac.fj/8647/1/LDA_review_IJMLC.pdf), you can see a survey of various approaches such as regularized LDA, Orthogonal LDA, Uncorrelated LDA, and Null Space LDA.

Comment: Wow very interesting. So, a possible solution could be to replace the inverse matrix by the pseudo inverse?

Comment: yes, that is called pseudo-inverse LDA in the survey. Note the remark though: It can be observed that the null space of within-class scatter matrix is discard which would sacrifice some discriminant information.